# Как разрешить доступ к определенной папке на сервере Apache ? .htaccess WP

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, apache

Есть сайт на движке `Wordpress`. Сервер: `Apache Version 2.4.37`.

`.htaccess` настроен так, что позволяет переходить только по файлам в корневой папке (public_html).

У меня есть подкаталог: public_html/folder1. В этом подкаталоге  есть файлы: index.php, test.php и т.д. Как разрешить доступ к этим файлам?

Допустим мой домен "example.ru", при переходе на "http://example.ru/folder1/index.php" сейчас ошибка 404. Как разрешить данную директорию? Возможно добавить некоторое исключение, чтобы и wp работал и можно было перейти в этот свой подкаталог и выполнять свои скрипты?

Содержимое моего .htaccess:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress

                        # BEGIN GZIP COMPRESSION BY TOOLBOX
                        <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
                            #add content typing
                            AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
                            AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
                            # Insert filters
                            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
                            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
                            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
                            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
                            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
                            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
                            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
                            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
                            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
                            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
                            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
                            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
                            # Drop problematic browsers
                            BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
                            BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
                            BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
                        </IfModule>
                        # END GZIP COMPRESSION
                        # BEGIN EXPIRY COMPRESSION BY TOOLBOX
                        <IfModule mod_expires.c>
                        # Enable expirations
                            ExpiresActive On 
                        # Default directive
                            ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
                         # My favicon
                         ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
                         # Images
                         ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
                         ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
                         ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
                         ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
                         # CSS
                         ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
                         # Javascript
                         ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
                         ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
                         ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
                         #ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
                         #ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"

                         #Header set Cache-Control “max-age=2692000, public”
                         #Header set Cache-Control “max-age=600, private, must-revalidate”
                         #Header unset ETag
                         #Header unset Last-Modified
                    </IfModule>
                    # END EXPIRY COMPRESSION
                    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Не изобретай костылей, а используй родной хтацесс ВП и . Он ничего не запрещает при физическом наличии файлов.

Comment: @SeVlad, сейчас вроде дэфолтный htaccess wp стоит (как в вопросе). При переходе в по адресу: "exmple.com/folder/index.php" возвращает ошибку 404. Физически файл точно существует. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @SeVlad,  в WP папки пускает. Например /wp-content/ без проблем заходит.

Но если в корне сайта создать свою папку, то при переходе - ошибка 404.

Comment: Ещё раз: у ВП нет никаких запретов при физическом существовании каталогов и файлов.

Comment: @SeVlad, ок. В какую сторону копнуть? Что может запрещать открывать папки не относящиеся к WP? .htaccess неверно настроен?

Comment: Используй родной хтацесс ВП. Он ничего не запрещает при физическом наличии файлов.

Comment: @SeVlad, Вы вопрос читали? Чем тот .htaccess что я указал в вопросе отличается  от дэфолтного? Как я вижу он и есть дэфолтный, родной, стандартный, базовый. [BASIC WP HTACCESS](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)

Comment: @SeVlad, возможно вы имеете ввиду "Multisite" конфигурацию .htaccess?

Comment: В дефолтном хтацессе всего 6 строк. 2 из которых прямо говорят про то что я выше 3 раза сказал.

Comment: @SeVlad, очень тактично с твоей стороны Я пробовал даже полностью оставив 6 строк как в BASE и опять-же ошибка 404. Выше спрашивал, что может еще влиять.. Ты мне как мантру что ВП не может мешать.. Если все что ты можешь подсказать: "у ВП нет никаких запретов при физическом существовании каталогов и файлов", то спасибо - не помог. Откланивайся..